# Selecting range of elements with jQuery and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to select a range of anchor elements using nth-child pseudo selector. The problem is that nth-child will work only with child elements, but I have a structure like this:

```
<div>
  <a>first link>
</div>
<div>
  <a>Second link</a>
</div>
<div>
  <a>Third link</a>
</div>
```

In this case, the following selector that I found useful for selecting first 2 matched elements doesn't work:

```
$("a:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n+2)")
```

I created an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/o6w5orom/ , in the first example all the elements are returned instead of first 2. In the second one works but only with direct children.

So, is there a way to construct CSS selector for jQuery that will basically return a range of elements, something like nth-child, but will work on matched elements of a jQuery object ? I want to construct the selector, don't wan't to write logic to process a jQuery object.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/ can this help ?

Comment: @Phill The problem is that nth-child doesn't work if selected elements are not children and siblings, so I'm looking for alternative way to select range.

Comment: [jQuery.findInRange](https://github.com/JDMcKinstry/jQuery.findInRange/blob/master/jQuery.findInRange.js) Use as simple as: `$('parentEle').findInRange('selectorOne', 'selectorTwo');`

Answer (score 0):

Use: `$("div:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n+2) a")`

Select the divs with the `nth-child` then descend to the `a`'s

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right - :nth-child returns only direct children.
But what's the problem? Use find.

> `$("div:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n+2)").find('a')`